# Wagtail CheckConstraint, column live does not exists

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I have such model

```
from wagtail.models import Page


class Article(Page):
    price = PositiveIntegerField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            CheckConstraint(check=Q(price__gte=100) & Q(live=True), name="min price for published"),
            CheckConstraint(check=Q(price__lte=350000) & Q(live=True), name="max price for published"),
        ]
```

After running makemigrations everything is fine. But when I try to execute it I got an error `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "live" does not exist`

How could that possible be? **live** column is part of Page. How this can be fixed?

Comment: Because Django uses an extra table to emulate inheritance, the `live` is not in the `Article` table, but the one generated for the `Page`, so that constraint is not possible to enforce at the database level.

Answer (score 1):

Page models in Wagtail make use of [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance), where the fields defined on the base Page class (such as `live`) are part of the `wagtailcore_page` table, while fields defined on your own page models (such as `price` here) are in a separate table. Check constraints are enforced at the database level, and so it isn't possible to define constraints that involve fields from more than one table.

It may be possible to approximate the behaviour of check constraints at the Python / Django level, by testing the relevant fields within the `save` method and raising an exception if the condition fails.